# AngularJS & Google Maps API V3 Cannot Geocode an Address in a Loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, for-loop

I am trying to geocode markers for each one in an AngularJS scope which can be picked up by using `$scope.locations`

I keep receiving the following error `TypeError: Cannot call method 'geocode' of undefined`

I have set `var geocoder, geocode, geocode_results;` at the top of my file

In an example, `$scope.location` has the following data when I console.log it.

```
$$hashKey: "009"    
desc: "Closest test"
gps: "ab42 2dl"
title: "A place"
```

The code I am using to try run through the loop of locations is the following.

```
$scope.plotmarkers = function() {
    console.log($scope);
//          var temp_addresses = document.getElementById("gps").value.split("\n");
            var temp_addresses = $scope.locations;
            console.log(temp_addresses);

            for(var i=0;i<temp_addresses.length;i++){
        //      addresses.push(temp_addresses[i]);
console.log(temp_addresses[i].gps);
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': temp_addresses[i].gps}, function(response, status) {
                    geocode_results[i] = new Array();
                    geocode_results[i]['status'] = status;
console.log('2')
                    if (!response || status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS){
                            geocode_results[i]['lat'] = 0;
                            geocode_results[i]['lng'] = 0;
                        } else {
                            timeouts++;
                            if(timeouts>6){
                                alert("You have reached the limit of of requests that you can make to google from this IP address in one day.");
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        timeouts = 0;
                        top_location = response[0];
                        var lat = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lat() * 1000000)/1000000;
                        var lng = Math.round(top_location.geometry.location.lng() * 1000000)/1000000;
                        geocode_results[i]['lat'] = lat;
                        geocode_results[i]['lng'] = lng;
                        geocode_results[i]['l_type'] = top_location.geometry.location_type;
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            icon: mapIcon,
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
                            map: map
                        });
                        arrayLocation.push(top_location.address_components[0].long_name);
        //              console.log(top_location.address_components[0].long_name);
                    }
                });
            }

    };
```

Comment: How are you initializing geocoder? If looks as if it is undefined by the time you call geocode in plotmarkers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```